# Theming and designing css in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

Ok, I know this is a general question, but I **really** looked information for a long time, and couldn't find helpful info that helped me.

I almost finish developing my community site in Drupal 7. Now I am starting to design it. I chose Zen theme, and created sub-theme.

Can you please recommend me about the best convenient method to **implement CSS to DRUPAL site**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, requests for tutorials are off-topic here - if you have a specific question about a problem you're having implementing CSS in Drupal, please edit the question to ask it. Please don't ask about CSS syntax/specificity or anything like that as questions about the language itself are also off-topic (but can of course be asked on Stack Overflow); it just needs to be a Drupal-specific question for this site. Thanks

Comment: I reworded my question. how can I remove the [on hold] feature, and get my question back live again? I will really appreciate help here..

Comment: @EdenBitton I'm sorry, but we do need to keep this closed; it's still a very broad topic.  My suggestion would be to pick up the Packt book *Drupal 7 Themes*, Cederholm's *Web Standards Solutions* and *Handcrafted CSS*, and Budd's *CSS Mastery*.  Those will get you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's  very vast topic, however few things I would like to share with you are:

- The best place to start can be the documentation of ZEN theme: https://drupal.org/node/193318. They are having pretty good maintained doc.
- Must go through tutorial is drupal's theming guide: https://drupal.org/documentation/theme
- To undertand the basics of theming: http://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-theming-basics-drupal-7
- How to create the subtheme: [here is official doc on how to create a sub-theme as per drupal standard](https://drupal.org/node/225125).
- Also there is one nice video tutorial on creating a sub-theme of Zen: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-IXpbdgA3A
- One good answer on creating a theme with drush command: [How do I create a Zen's sub-theme using Drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82160/how-do-i-create-a-zens-sub-theme-using-drush)
- Moving further you can check how do drupal process theme variables for templates: [Setting up variables for use in a template (preprocess and process functions)](https://drupal.org/node/223430)
- It would be good to learn few of the CSS frameworks: [SASS framework](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html), [LESS framework](http://lesscss.org/)

I tried to cover few of the quick points that striked me first, but anyways there is no limit of learning, so keep on exploring!!